# How to access attributes of object literals in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can you tell me what is wrong with this javascript code? It seems like the countries array is not getting initialized correctly, because it doesn't even make it past the initialization to the second document.write("test2"); line:

```
<script>
document.write("test1");
var countries;
countries = [
    {
        name: 'France',
        continent: 'Europe',
        cities: ['Paris', 'Nice'],
        photos: [france1.jpg, france2.jpg]
    },
    {
        name: 'Mexico',
        continent: 'North America',
        cities: ['Tijuana', 'Cancun', 'Mexico City'],
        photos: [mexico1.jpg, mexico2.jpg, mexico3.jpg]
    },
    {
        name: 'China',
        continent: 'Asia',
        cities: ['Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Hong Kong'],
        photos: [china1.jpg, china2.jpg]
    }
];
document.write("test2");
document.write(countries[0].name);

</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser's developer console. Likely because the photo names are not strings?

Comment: Are your photos supppsed to be string names of images?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is basically just a typo type problem. By the way, what does the question title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'photos' need to be quoted. For example,

```
{
    name: 'France',
    continent: 'Europe',
    cities: ['Paris', 'Nice'],
    photos: ['france1.jpg', 'france2.jpg']
}
```

A quick check of your Javascript error console should have shown you this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to qoute the strings (‘france1.jpg,‘)in the photos variable.